# Macro code to generate a formatted Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a database in my Excel with this format

```
Cosumer    Date    Ref #    Product Code    Description    U/M   Qty   Price   Transaction
```

I want a macro code which when I run it, a dialog text box will appear indicating "Start Date" and "End Date" and after encoding the start date and end date, it will generate a new excel file that has this format:

[image]

I hope someone will help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: This looks like it could be a lot of work. What have you tried so far? At the very least, you're going to need to create a userform to retrieve the start date and end date.

Comment: What I've already done is using functions in excel, a lot of vlookups and some other functions just to filter the data that I need in that form and that's giving a heavy toll on excel making it slow.

Comment: Please understand that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. People are not here to solve your issue for you but to **assist you to solve your issue yourself**. Therefore you need to show your code with a **detailed** description of … (1) what the code actually does, (2) where you got stuck and (3) if there are any error messages and where they occur. If possible give a [mcve] of your issue. Also read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) to understand why your question is too broad to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this.

```
Public Sub MyFilter()
    Dim lngStart As Long, lngEnd As Long
    lngStart = Range("E1").Value 'assume this is the start date
    lngEnd = Range("E2").Value 'assume this is the end date
    Range("C1:C13").AutoFilter field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & lngStart, _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:="<=" & lngEnd
End Sub
```

All details are here.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/910-excel-filter-between-two-dates.html